# 3D shopping experience

Tags: 3d, web

I want to create a virtual shop in 3D in a website and make the logged in customer shop in 3D experience ,  picking product and billing also in 3D VIEW what all technologies will involve in this

Comment: Sorry, but this question is way too general. First of all: Do you want to use a shop framework (like Magento) or do you want to program it yourself? If framework: Check some plugins/extensions for 3D view. If you want to program it yourself, what tech stack do you want to use? This forum is more for specific programming questions (preferably with code examples) rather than entire project tutorials/estimations :)

Comment: To be true, i didnt start coding for this , m jus checking to make this possible.  If anyone could lemme know all the requisites to implement this , i can do some more R&D . I want a shop in 3D with products displayed and logged in customer to buy from it

Answer (score 0):

What's your tech stack? If you're familiar with PHP & HTML/CSS/JavaScript I would start off with a frmework (my preference is Magento. If you want a "simpler" solution, check WooCommerce). 
The basic setup for a framework is pretty simple. you can check various tutorials on the internet, like this one:

https://www.nchannel.com/blog/magento-setup-guide/

However, I would recommend you to get familiar with the used programming languages, that makes many things easier.

If you have a working environment, you can check for plugins letting you view your products in 3D. 
I just googled that and found this plugin which ooks pretty neat (however, I've never used that so far):

https://marketplace.magento.com/webrotate360-webrotate360-catalog.html

But I assume for you the best way would be to make some research before you start off in order to get familiar with the techniques :)

Comment: i want to do in c#.net lemme know if it is a good idea
thanks for responding

Comment: Well, in my opinion the most important thing is to use an existing shop framework (like I mentioned in my last posts), sice you save a lot of work. C# & .net are solid technologies you could go with. However, I don't know any tool/shop framework for it (I'm sure there are some, I'm just not familier with them). 
From tech stack point of view I would go for PHP (with Zend Framework) (easier for beginners), or my personal preference would be Java (with Spring). It's more advanced, but way more solid with its strictness, typings, package structure etc.